# How to externalize .property file from classpath?

Tags: websphere, struts-1

Is there any way to keep struts ApplicationResource.property file outside of project directory and add location in Websphere jvm argument or custom property?
Property file contains the following info:-

Error.uname= ***

Error.pwd=xxx

It is configured in struts-config.xml file using message resources.
Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will be the entry in <message-resource> tag in struts-cofig file and how can I add java args for ApplicationResouces.property file if I place this file in external location?

Comment: Hi Team- can anyone please me on this.Let me know if any details are required.